# ng-model not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am using angularJs 1.6 and have two input type element on html with ng-model.
On `ng-click` I am have a function passing these value through the function to my controller

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From" id="fromlocation" name="mfrom" data-ng-model="mfrom"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="To" id="tolocation" name="mto" data-ng-model="mto"> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Estimate" data-ng-click="findDistance(mfrom,mto)">
</div>
```

function on controller

```
$scope.findDistance=function(source, destination)
{
    alert("source " + source + "destination " + destination);
    $scope.errorStatus = "false";

    if ((source == undefined || source == null || source == '') || (destination == undefined || destination == null || destination == ''))
    {
        $rootScope.setInvalidError();
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.source_address = source;
        $scope.destination_address = destination;
        $scope.initMap(); 
        $scope.getEstimatePrice(source, destination);
    }
}
```

Issue here is that when I debug on function in controller I don't get the complete text that is entered in input type. Only 4 character are transferred on function and this is uncertain sometime it works and sometime it don't. I don't know what is the exact issue.

Comment: Are you doing something in $scope.initMap() function? May be you are doing something here which is trimming the data.

Comment: I think, your function get undefined as parameters. Try to rewrite it like this <input type="button" data-ng-click="findDistance()"> and $scope.findDistance=function() { use $scope.mfrom and $scope.mto as arguments}

Comment: @RakeshBurbure through this I am iinitializing google map api , but before that I am checking for the values in alert it is not same as the inputed one. means it get trimmed some time upto 2 character also.

Comment: @DmitryLobov I have tried using that also but still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From" id="fromlocation" name="mfrom" data-ng-model="mfrom"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="To" id="tolocation" name="mto" data-ng-model="mto"> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Estimate" data-ng-click="findDistance()">
</div>
```

This way, you will have to access those input variables inside the handler function. Also, try to check wether `$scope.mfrom & $scope.mto` are being trimmed(maybe?) in another controller's function.

```
$scope.findDistance=function()
{
    let source = $scope.mfrom; //direcly obtained
    let destination = $scope.mto;
    //The rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

on html

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From" id="fromlocation" name="mfrom" ng-model="mfrom"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="To" id="tolocation" name="mto" ng-model="mto"> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Estimate" ng-click="findDistance(mfrom,mto)">
</div>
```

on js

```
$scope.mfrom = 'value1';
$scope.mto = 'value2';
```